# Looping through arguments in bash

Tags: bash, loops, arguments

I'm trying to write  a code that runs on my arguments list ,
for example if I have `-p a b c d -q g e f c` as arguments:
when I get `-p`, I want the loop to run on variables `a b c d`, until I get `-q`, and then to do something else,
likewise I want it to be in reverse;

this is my code:

```
#bin/bash
while test -n "$1" -a ${1:0:1} = - ;do
if test x$1=x-q:then
    shift
    while test -n "$1" ; do
        echo $1
        if test x$2=x-p;then 
            break;
        shift
    done
fi
if test x$1=x-p;then 
   echo 'print test'+$1;
   shift
fi
done
```

but break doesn't seem to work, does anyone know how I can implement this?

Comment: Can you narrow it down a little bit? I'm not sure whether your actual question is "Why is this syntax invalid?" or "Why doesn't `shift` run after `break`?" or "Why is `test x$1=x-p` always true?"

Comment: `test x$1=x-q:then` you have `:` where you need `;`. Is that a copying error?

Comment: the code runs fine, the error is in the break; what is the proper syntax for that?

Comment: You're missing a `fi` for the `if`.

Comment: You should quote your variables.

Comment: `-a` is obsolete and all but deprecated; use `test -n "$1" && test ${1:0:1} = -` instead.

Comment: Please run your code through shellcheck.net for bugs. Also, if you're explicitly using bash in your shebang (missing a slash there?), try `[[ ... ]]` instead of `test ...`. It's a step up in almost every case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider first parsing all the arguments, and collection the "-p" args in one array and the "-q" args in another array:

```
p_args=() 
q_args=()
opt=""

for arg do 
    case $arg in 
        "-p") opt=p ;; 
        "-q") opt=q ;; 
           *) [[ $opt == p ]] && p_args+=("$arg")
              [[ $opt == q ]] && q_args+=("$arg")
              ;; 
    esac
done

# do stuff with "-p" args
declare -p p_args

# do stuff with "-q" args
declare -p q_args
```

Comment: a semicolon (or newline) before the do is allowed. (for arg; do)